# WordPress cookie not working

Tags: wordpress, cookies, plugins

Hello

I'm designing a wordpress plugin and I want to use a cookie.
Here is my code:

```html
<?PHP
/**
 * Plugin Name: COOKIEss

function foobar_func( $atts ){

function set_user_cookie() {
    $school = "Some Value";
   setcookie("sevisitor", 1, time()+3600, "/", ".domain.com");


}
add_action( 'init', 'set_user_cookie');

}



add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
function foobar_funcs( $atts ){
 echo $_COOKIE['sevisitor']; 

}
add_shortcode( 'ss', 'foobar_funcs' );
```

I have copied and pasted everything so I make sure everything works! But it is still not working and I do not know why.
Also for header I get bool(false). I used wp_debug and it told me that sevisitor is not defined!
Please help!!
Thank you
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortcodes must **return** not echo a variable otherwise nothing will show up.  Use this code instead, it's always a good idea to check if a cookie has been set before you access it.

```
function set_user_cookie() {
    setcookie( 'sevisitor', true, current_time('timestamp') + HOUR_IN_SECONDS, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
}

add_action( 'init', 'set_user_cookie');

add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );

function foobar_func() {
    if( isset( $_COOKIE['sevisitor'] ) )
        return $_COOKIE['sevisitor']; 
}

//To show the value of the cookie use this function in your php template file

echo do_shortcode( '[foobar]' );
```

Comment: hi again sir!
I have a new problem. My setcookie is not working again after i did a lot of other modifications.

Comment: Would you please check my new question that includes my new code?

Comment: @MAHDI what's the link to the new question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205548/setcookie-not-working-wordpress-because-of-header