# setcookie not working wordpress because of header

Tags: wordpress, cookies, plugins, setcookie

I have a WordPress plugin that wants to create cookies but it doesn't work. I would really appreciate a help.

```html
add_shortcode( 'watchlist', 'cwatchlist_short' );
  
function cwatchlist_short() {
 echo '<div class="wrap"><center>';
echo "<form method='POST' action=''";
echo '<p>Please enter the initial of the cryptocurrency or the symbol you want to add to the watchlist!</p> <p>For example: BTC</p>';
 echo "<p><input type='text' name='symbol' placeholder='Initials or symbol'>";
 
 
   echo "<p><input type='submit' value='Submit'>";
   echo "</form></center>";
 echo '</div>';
 if (isset($_POST["symbol"])){
  $x = $_COOKIE['xvalue'] + 1;
setcookie( 'xvalue', $x, time() + 108000, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN   );
```

debugging shows: `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent` by
I really need help.
Thank you
best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setcookie function can not work on direct page run process, its always throw header already set error message.
To solve this issue must use new function for setcookie & add this function on init action.

For Ex.

```html
add_action( 'init', 'my_setcookie_example' );
function my_setcookie_example() {
 setcookie( "name", "value", time(), "/", COOKIE_DOMAIN );
}
```

In Your case,need to remove "setcookie( 'xvalue', $x, time() + 108000, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN   );" & place into function, After that add "add_action" hook on place of it.

Comment: Thank you! I combined your way with a way I thought could worked. It is easier this way! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a cookie in a shortcode function because the headers have already been sent by WordPress.  setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers, so if you want to set a cookie value it needs to be added in a hook prior or during the **send_headers** hook.

Comment: So how can I do my job? How can I set a cookie after the user has filled and sent the form?

Comment: Use the hook wp_admin to process the form, you'll need to do some reading on it.  https://www.sitepoint.com/handling-post-requests-the-wordpress-way/

Answer (score 0):

Please use `ob_start();` function at the top of the file and `ob_end_flush()` function after the code where you want to use cookies.

**ob_start function:** Turns on output buffering.

**ob_end_clean function:** Clears buffer and closes buffering.

For more details http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Comment: I tried to use the function but it didn't work. I think I've messed up a part.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of your answers! The OB_START didn't work for me maybe there was a problem in my code but I couldn't use it. 
The admin post was also a great way to solve it but the easier way for me was to change my code less and I used the add_action inside my function.

```html
add_shortcode( 'watchlist', 'cwatchlist_short' );
  add_action( 'init', 'my_setcookie_example' );
  add_action( 'init', 'my_setcookie_isset');
function my_setcookie_isset() {
if(isset($_COOKIE['xvalue'])){

} else{
setcookie ("xvalue","0",time() + 108000, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
}
if (isset($_COOKIE['thejson'])){
} else{
setcookie ("thejson"," ",time() + 108000, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
}
}
function my_setcookie_example() {
if (isset($_POST["symbol"])){
    
     setcookie ("thejson","1",time() + 108000, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
```

So basically what I did was to add a new function that was going to be run before the header and it checked if the form was completed or not. If textbobx SYMBOL was completed then I set a cookie. Also I set all of my cookies with a nonimportant value to have no error during the process.
So if you have a problem except setting a cookie inside a shortcode and a function that check isset of a textbox. Run that function usuing INIT before the header!

Thank you to all because this is my conclusion from all of your answers and ideas and links!

Best Regards